# Sony USB3.0 stick (USM64GXL) not recognized

Tags: 14.10, usb-drive, sony

My Ubuntu 14.10 installation doesn't recognize my USB stick. Could anyone help me? `lsusb` sees the device, but not `fdisk` or any other tool.

I thought I had problems with `libmtp` and uninstalled it, without success.

**Product: Sony USM64GXL** - USB-STICK X-SERIES 64GB USB3.0 - BLUE/5YW/ SW

Output of lsusb:

```
Bus 004 Device 005: ID 054c:09c2 Sony Corp.
```

Output of dmesg:

```
[  241.322233] usb 4-2: new SuperSpeed USB device number 4 using xhci_hcd
[  241.435827] usb 4-2: New USB device found, idVendor=054c, idProduct=09c2
[  241.435830] usb 4-2: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[  241.435832] usb 4-2: Product: Storage Media
[  241.435834] usb 4-2: Manufacturer: Sony
[  241.435835] usb 4-2: SerialNumber: 5C0710533189156A62
```

What should I do? Do I miss a driver, can I add one to the kernel with `insmod`?

Comment: I've just upgraded my system to Ubuntu 15.10, nothing has changed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've finally found the solution. The following line in my configuration file `/etc/modprobe.d/gm12u320.conf` was blocking the way, probably preventing the usb-storage driver from loading:

```
install usb-storage /sbin/modprobe --ignore-install gm12u320 && /sbin/modprobe --ignore-install usb-storage
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this workaround and see if it helps:

Create a new file like quirks.conf in /etc/modprobe.d/

```
sudo -i
nano /etc/modprobe.d/quirks.conf
```

Put the following line:

```
options usb-storage quirks=054c:09c2:u
```

The format is quirks=::u where  is the VendorId and  is the ProductId of your quirky usb device, which may be found via lsusb. The 'u' flag disables uas for the device.

It is advisable that you do this before you attach the device to the system.

Comment: Thank you for the advice... sadly it doesn't seem to work. I'm wondering why nothing else is showing up in dmesg. Shouldn't I see more messages after plugging the device?